# Is there any solution for install docker toolbox on centos?

Tags: docker

I need to install docker toolbox for use kitematic and other solutions for managing my images. But didn't find any solution for Centos.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com) and the Kitematic [github repository](https://github.com/docker/kitematic),  Docker-Toolbox and Kitematic have never been natively produced for the linux environment besides MacOS. Furthermore, the Toolbox is now superseeded by other solutions for Windows and MacOS offered by Docker. Kitematic is still maintained though, but only for Ubuntu, Windows and MacOS.

If you **have to** install Kitematic, there is a .deb-file for ubuntu hosted at the [Kitematic github repository.](https://github.com/docker/kitematic) You could try porting it to an .rpm-file installing and using [alien](https://www.systutorials.com/241786/how-to-install-alien-on-centos-7-to-convert-deb-to-rpm/). The seemingly offical [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alien-pkg-convert/) entry is quite empty, but there are several websites and tutorials documenting the usage.

Otherwise, if you search for a GUI to manage docker images, you could take a look at [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/). It is a docker web frontend and platform independet due to being deployed as a docker image.